# Sphinx killlist query

Tags: sphinx

I don't know why killlist is not working properly ?

My sphinx.conf looks like that:

```
source main
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        =
    sql_db          = sphinx

    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO sph_counter SELECT 1, MAX(id) FROM documents
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT id, group_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added, title, content \
        FROM documents \
        WHERE id<=( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )

    sql_attr_uint       = group_id
    sql_field_string        = title
    sql_attr_timestamp  = date_added

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id=$id
}

source delta : main
{
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query = SELECT id, group_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added, title, content \
        FROM documents \
        WHERE id>( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )

    sql_query_killlist = \
    SELECT id FROM documents WHERE date_added>=@last_reindex UNION \
    SELECT id FROM documents_deleted WHERE deleted_ts>=@last_reindex
}

index main
{
    source = main
    path = C:/Sphinx/data/main
    # ... all the other settings

}

# note how all other settings are copied from main,
# but source and path are overridden (they MUST be)
index delta : main
{
    source = delta
    path = C:/Sphinx/data/delta
 }
```

**When I update one item in database date_added is changed and also content I still get old result even after delta index was refreshed ??**

Comment: Where is @last_reindex defined? Its not a magic sphinx variable, its a standard MySQL user-variable. So you need to define it somewhere.

Comment: you need to update your indexes